# smarty PHP отображает не все данные после обновления

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Вечер добрый.
Столкнулся с проблемой. Попробую проиллюстрировать кусочком псевдо-кода.

- smarty->debugging = true;
- smarty->caching = FALSE;
- Обновление страницы на AJAX

  $запрос_к_википедии["ответ3"]="ответ"; // в базе уже есть "ответ1" и ответ2"
  $запись_в_базу = $запрос_к_википедии["ответ3"];
  $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"] = массив // запрос к базе чтобы
  // получить все данные, 
  // в том числе и только что записанные (одно из полей генерируется самим mysql)
          (
          "ответ1"
          "ответ2"
          "ответ3"
          );

  передаю в шаблон smarty $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"]
  отображаются только

  "ответ1"
     "ответ2".

При чем если сделать var_dump($запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"])
там все ответы. Т.к.  видно что передается весь массив, кроме последнего значения.
Если повторить итерацию и получить **"ответ4"**, то смарти покажет

```
   "ответ1"  
   "ответ2"
   "ответ3"
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если у вас в скрипте сформирован массив и вы его передаете через $smarty->assign('wikipedia_query',  $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"]), тогда проблемы с использованием в смарти данного массива через переменную $wikipedia_query быть не должно.

Comment: Да передаю именно так как вы сказали. Но проблема, увы есть. В теле скрипта var_damp показывает, что $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"]("ответ1","ответ2"). А страница дебага смарти показывает, что $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"]("ответ1"). Т.е. отображение "отстает" на один запрос.Может ли это быть какое то кеширование на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Сам дурак, была логическая ошибка в коде.
Мне нужно было взять последний элемент массива $запрос_к_википедии["запрос_к_базе"] и я воспользовался **array_pop**, не внимательно прочитав в описании работы функции, что она **извлекает** и **возвращает** последний элемент массива.